# Custom logic for dropping duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

I have the following dataset that I'm hoping to apply some custom logic to:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A','B','B','C','C','D','D'], 
'Date': ['2018-07-02T02:21:12.000+0000','2018-07-02T02:28:29.000+0000','2018-07-02T02:28:31.000+0000','2018-07-02T02:30:58.000+0000','2018-07-02T02:31:01.000+0000','2018-07-02T02:42:46.000+0000','2018-07-02T02:41:47.000+0000'],
'Action': ['Start','Start','Start','Stop','Stop','Start','Start'],
'Group': [5,13,13,19,19,2,2],
'Value': [100,110,110,95,95,280,280]
})
```

Rows 1:2, 3:4, and 5:6 are all identical except for the values in the Date column, which are off by a matter of seconds. Is there a way to remove duplicates if 1) the "date" timedelta between similar rows is less than 1 minute and 2) all other information is identical?

The result should look like the following:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({
'ID': ['A','B','C','D'], 
'Date': ['2018-07-02T02:21:12.000+0000','2018-07-02T02:28:29.000+0000','2018-07-02T02:30:58.000+0000','2018-07-02T02:42:46.000+0000'],
'Action': ['Start','Start','Stop','Start'],
'Group': [5,13,19,2],
'Value': [100,110,95,280]
})
```

Comment: This can be ambiguous. Say you have multiple rows within a 2 minute period. Which 1 minute slot do you choose to group by?

Comment: jpp makes a very good point. The solution I provided cascades, meaning that if you had 10 measurements all 59 seconds apart, you would still only keep the first measurement, and consider the other 9 duplicates. Perhaps this is what you want, but if not, you will need to perform some other type of bucketing. If you only ever have 2 dates for each group it wont really be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the logic you want can be accomplished with a self merge using `pd.merge_asof`, which allows for a combination of matching on exact keys and `nearest` keys.

You will exclude exact matches, and use the default `backward` direction, which means that you will always keep only the earliest time entry in the case that two (or more) entries occur within the specified time window.

```
import pandas as pd

data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)
data = data.sort_values('Date')

merged = pd.merge_asof(
              data, 
              data.rename(columns={'Date': 'Date2'}), 
              by=[x for x in data.columns if x != 'Date'], 
              left_on='Date', right_on='Date2',
              direction='backward',
              allow_exact_matches=False)

# Remove duplicates within 1 minute
merged[((merged.Date - merged.Date2) > pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)) | (merged.Date2.isnull())].drop(columns='Date2')
```

Outputs:

```
  ID                Date Action  Group  Value
0  A 2018-07-02 02:21:12  Start      5    100
1  B 2018-07-02 02:28:29  Start     13    110
3  C 2018-07-02 02:30:58   Stop     19     95
5  D 2018-07-02 02:41:47  Start      2    280
```